NPM Workspace monorepo: TSC fails with module not found for imports in library
I have the following setup for the npm monorepo: https://github.com/ChristianKernDev/monorepo_playground
Everything works as expected, except the tsc command, which shows the following error:
../common/src/index.ts:1:17 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'test/a' or its corresponding type declarations.
This means, that the compiler can not correctly import direct paths in a submodule. How can i fix this?

Please import from ''./test/a'', otherwise a module is expected. If you want this. Please define this in the tsconfig. But i guess you want just from the file.

Please do not link to an external code source. Instead provide the necessary snippets here directly.

There are multiple points:

Your workspace setup works without running npm link. See relevant docs. Just running npm install is enough.
Add a reference to common lib in app/tsconfig.json:

{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "references": [
    { "path": "../common" }
  ],
  "include": [
    ...
  ]
}


Now for the reference to work make the following changes in base tsconfig

Replace the noEmit in base tsconfig with emitDeclarationOnly so that the type declarations for 'common' lib are generated (credit).
Set composite to true to enable declaration.



{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "composite": true
  },
}


Now you could build all the workspaces using the following command in project root:

npm run --workspaces


Perfect fix thanks! Also i didn't know you don't need the npm link, but that also works so also thanks for that :)
